# How to set up build and release pipeline for NestJS application to Azure using YAML

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nestjs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am having trouble understanding and getting the build/release pipelines setup for deploying a NestJS application to Azure DevOps (ADO).

I am deploying to a Linux Web App hosted in Azure.

As far as I understand, if I run the app locally using something like `npm run start`, it creates a `dist` folder under my root project directory.

So, when writing the YAML for the build and deployment. My thought process is to:

1. Run an NPM update.
2. Run `npm run build` to build the application and generate the `dist` folder.
3. Copy the contents of the application (or just the dist folder?) into the target folder (`/home/site/wwwroot`)
4. Run `npm run start:prod` to start the server.

Here is my YAML so far:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: UseNode@1
  inputs:
    version: '14.x'
    checkLatest: true

- task: Npm@0
  displayName: Run NPM Update for NestJS
  inputs:
    cwd: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ProjectName'
    command: update

- task: Npm@0
  displayName: Build NestJS
  inputs:
    cwd: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/ProjectName'
    command: run
    arguments: "build"

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: 'dist/**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

The issue is after the build process completes, I do not see a `dist` folder in `/home/site/wwwroot/ProjectName`. Can someone help me out with what I am missing?

Also, a side noob-y question about Azure DevOps, what does `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` and `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` refer to and how and where are those environment variables set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deploy your app to the  hosted in Azure. You need to use [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) or [Azure Web App task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app?view=azure-devops).

Azure devops is the tool to build and deploy your app to your server(eg. the Linux Web App on Azure), it is not for hosting your app.

`$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` refer to the folder of the agent machine which runs your pipeline. (When your run your pipeline, it pick up a agent defined in `pool` to run your pipeline tasks)

The mapping to the folders in the agent machine is showing as below screenshot. Check the [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for more information.

[image]

> `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)` is mapped to c:\agent_work\1
>
> `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` is mapped to c:\agent_work\1\a
>
> `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)` is mapped to c:\agent_work\1\b
>
> `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` is mapped to c:\agent_work\1\s

So back to the question how to deploying a NestJS application to Azure?

First you need to create a service connection in Azure devops to connect to your azure subscription. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps.

Then add `Azure App Service Deploy task`/`Azure Web App task` to the end of your pipeline. See below example:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'SubscriptionServiceConnectionName'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    WebAppName: 'MyWebAppName'
    Package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist/'
    StartupCommand: 'npm run start:prod'
```

You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp-linux?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnet-core%2Cyaml) for more information.